# error: ‘list’ is not a member of ‘std’ and error: template argument 2 is invalid

Tags: c++, list, c++11, dictionary, std

I'm trying to compile my header file, but I'm getting errors I can't figure out.

I want to create a struct that contains 3 maps:
-map from single words to counts
-map from word pairs to counts
-map from single words to list of following words

The code in my header file:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <map>

typedef struct {

    std::map<std::string, int> firstCounts;
    std::map<std::string, int> pairCounts;
    std::map<std::string, std::list<std::string>> follows; //You can use an iterator to retrieve the values stored in the list. 

} LanguageModel;
```

And the errors I'm getting:

```
>   LangModel.h:24:23: error: ‘list’ is not a member of ‘std’
>      std::map<std::string, std::list<std::string>> follows; //You can use an iterator to retrieve the values stored in the list. 
>                            ^
>     LangModel.h:24:23: error: ‘list’ is not a member of ‘std’
>     LangModel.h:24:38: error: template argument 2 is invalid
>      std::map<std::string, std::list<std::string>> follows; //You can use an iterator to retrieve the values stored in the list. 
>                                           ^
>     LangModel.h:24:38: error: template argument 4 is invalid
>     LangModel.h:24:44: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘>’ token
>      std::map<std::string, std::list<std::string>> follows; //You can use an iterator to retrieve the values stored in the list.
```

Answer (score 21):

You forgot to add

```
#include <list>
```

Comment: thanks! I forgot about that.

Also, is there anything wrong with including libraries in a header file that might not be used?

Comment: The compiler has more work to do but for a simple program it's not of concern. Except for its redundancy...

Comment: Adding `#include` lines in a `.h` file has compile time cost. Don't `#include` anything in a `.h` file unless you need to.

Answer (score 7):

What about `#include <list>`? You are missing the header inclusion.